# Mapguide and OpenLayers SRS WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text

I am trying to create OpenLayers vector features based on WKT strings that I retrieve from a MapGuide server.  I have successfully gotten the proper geometry to be rendered, but I do not know how to handle the SRS WKT string.  As a result, the vectors are being placed in the north end of the DR of Congo rather than eastern Pennsylvania.

I was able to retrieve the SRS WKT string:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1968500.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-77.75],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",39.93333333333333],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",40.96666666666667],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",39.33333333333334],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

What would be the best way to handle this?  The base map is in EPSG: 900913.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was with OpenLayers silently failing when attempting to transform the vector features to the proper projection as a result of proj4js not being properly referenced.

I was able to find the proper originating projection from spatialreference.org and get the projection code to base the transforms on.

I also discovered that spatialreference.org has no official record of EPSG:900913 (which I expected) or EPSG:3875 (which I did not expect).  I needed to use EPSG:3785 which I thought was deprecated.